# TypeError: Object of type Interval is not JSON serializable in Plotly, Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plotly

I have converted a continuous variable, x, into interval. And i have a y variable with numerical values. The dataframe is:

```
data = {'x':[(-0.001, 7.0], (7.0, 19.0], (19.0, 97.0], (97.0, 817.0]],
        'y':[769.0, 810.0,757.0,652.0]}

# Create DataFrame      
df = pd.DataFrame(data)  
df
```

The data types for both these variables are `float64`. Furthermore, the description for variable 'x' is given as:

```
Name: x, dtype: category
Categories (4, interval[float64]): [(-0.001, 7.0] < (7.0, 19.0] < (19.0, 97.0] < (97.0, 817.0]]
```

Now, i'm using plotly to graph the relationship between these two variables:

```
# figure
plot_data = [
    go.Scatter(
        x = df['x'],
        y = df['y'])]

plot_layout = go.Layout(title=' Relationship between x and y')               
fig = go.Figure(data=plot_data, layout=plot_layout)
pyoff.iplot(fig)
```

But the error shown is:

```
TypeError: Object of type Interval is not JSON serializable
```

So, as far as I understood, the variable 'x' is given as interval in a format which plotly is unable to identify. How to fix this? Is there any example known to you where one can use plotly to plot interval variable?

Comment: The `Interval` object is not JSON serializable - i.e. JSON lib doesn't know how to convert it to JSON format. You would need to implement a method for encoding the `Interval` on your side and decoding it on `plotly` back to interval or some adequate representation.
A workaround might be to list the interval with enough granularity i.e. `(1,100]` to `[1.0001, 1.01, 2, 3, ..., 100]` which should be OK with json.

Comment: By the way, what library do you use, that it allows you to write the interval like (1, 2]?

Comment: I'm using `pd.qcut` to divide it into four groups

Comment: @MarekSchwarz example code please.

Answer (score 17):

you only need to cast the column with ".astype('str')"