# Object of type Period is not JSON serializable in plotly

Tags: pandas, plotly

I am trying to plot a line chart. Below is my code

CODE :

```
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objects as go
flag = determineFlag('2020-03-01','2020-03-30')

df_r = getDataForTrend(df,'2020-03-01','2020-03-30','d')

colors = {
    'background': '#111111',
    'text': '#7FDBFF'
}



data = [go.Scatter(x = df_r[df_r['S2PName-Category']==category]['S2BillDate'],
                    y = df_r[df_r['S2PName-Category']==category]['totSale'],
                    mode = 'lines',
                    name = category) for category in df_r['S2PName-Category'].unique()]


layout = {'title':'Category Trend',
         'xaxis':{'title':'Time Frame'},
         'yaxis':{'title':'Total Sales Amount','tickformat' : '.2f'}}

fig = go.Figure(data=data,layout=layout)

pyo.iplot(fig)
```

when I run the above code I get the below error:

ERROR:

```
TypeError: Object of type Period is not JSON serializable
```

While tying to debug, I try to execute the below code

DEBUG CODE :

```
df_r[df_r['S2PName-Category']==category]['S2BillDate']
```

OP :

```
3     2020-03-01
11    2020-03-02
21    2020-03-03
26    2020-03-04
41    2020-03-06
42    2020-03-05
46    2020-03-07
Name: S2BillDate, dtype: period[D]
```

How can I fix the type error ? Is there any tweaks to this ? Any help is much appreciated! Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried converting that column of the dataframe to a date instead?

Comment: I did read them as dates , but later I had to perform dot.to-period like this basic_df_2 = basic_df.groupby(['S2PName-Category',basic_df['S2BillDate'].dt.to_period('M')], sort=False)['S2PGTotal'].agg([('totSale','sum')]).reset_index()

Comment: Take a look at https://community.plotly.com/t/modifying-extending-jsonencoder-for-panda-dataframe-timespan-objects/5179. Since a period encompasses more than one date, you'll have to make a sensible choice about what you want the string representation of the period to be.

Answer (score 8):

AFAIK this is still an issue and plotly will fail in such situation. There is still an open issue at github: [Support for Pandas Time spans as index col](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2764).

As proposed in the comments one of the solution is to use `to_timestatmp` conversion, see [this](https://community.plotly.com/t/modifying-extending-jsonencoder-for-panda-dataframe-timespan-objects/5179/3).

1. Create MWE (this is just for reproducibility since there is no data provided in the question)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.offline as pyo

df = pd.DataFrame({"one": np.random.random(10)}, index=pd.period_range("2020-03-01", freq="M", periods=10))
# Out:
#               one
# 2020-03  0.302359
# 2020-04  0.919923
# 2020-05  0.673808
# 2020-06  0.718974
# 2020-07  0.754675
# 2020-08  0.731673
# 2020-09  0.772382
# 2020-10  0.654555
# 2020-11  0.549314
# 2020-12  0.101696

data = [
    go.Scatter(
        x=df.index,
        y=df["one"],
    )
]
fig = go.Figure(data=data)
pyo.iplot(fig)
# -> will fail ("TypeError: Object of type Period is not JSON serializable")
```

2. Use `to_timestamp` conversion (-> `df.index.to_timestamp()`)

```
data = [
    go.Scatter(
        x=df.index.to_timestamp(), # period to datetime conversion
        y=df["one"],
    )
]
fig = go.Figure(data=data)
pyo.iplot(fig)
```

Or, if you do not need datetime format you can convert this to string as well:

```
data = [
    go.Scatter(
        x=df.index.strftime("%Y-%m"),  # You can define your own format
        y=df["one"],
    )
]
fig = go.Figure(data=data)
pyo.iplot(fig)
```

You can of course do this conversion right on the original dataframe (so you do not need to do it iteratively inside `go.Scatter`), but this is just minor stuff. There might be also a way of using custom encoder instead of the default one, but I think it's not worthy of trying and afaik there is no better solution than using one of possible conversion from `Period` to `datetime` or `string`.

Answer (score 0):

cast the column with `.astype('str')`

Credits to:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66770186/1726832