# convert float to string in pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, pivot, dtype

I want to create a heatmap with dimensions in x and y-axes. But I get an error message saying "Object of type Interval is not JSON serializable". When checking the dtypes of my table it's float64, after making it a pivot table. I think I need to convert it to string.

Below is the table I'm using is (with example avg-values):

| amount_binned | score_binned | avg_score | avg_converted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0-500 | 0%-0.5% | 0.02 | 0.05 |
| 0-500 | 0.5%-2% | 0.02 | 0.07 |
| 0-500 | 2%-6% | 0.02 | 0.02 |
| 500-5000 | 0%-0.5% | 0.02 | 0.05 |
| 500-5000 | 0.5%-2% | 0.02 | 0.07 |
| 500-5000 | 2%-6% | 0.02 | 0.07 |
| 5000-10000 | 0%-0.5% | 0.02 | 0.02 |
| 5000-10000 | 0.5%-2% | 0.02 | 0.02 |
| 5000-10000 | 2%-6% | 0.02 | 0.02 |

The bins' have category as dtype, 'avg_score' and 'avg_converted' have float64.

I'm creating a pivot out of above table with below code:

```
heatmap_data = df_grouped_heatmap.pivot(index='score_binned', columns='amount_binned')['converted'].fillna(0)
```

This resulted in everything in the table turning into floats, including the index and column 'score_binned' and 'amount_binned'.

I tried to use below code to turn it into a heatmap, but I got an error message saying "Object of type Interval is not JSON serializable", which I believe could be because of the index and column being floats.

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.imshow(heatmap_data, x=heatmap_data.columns, y=heatmap_data.index)
fig.update_layout(width=500,height=500)
fig.show()
```

I tried to convert the floats into string with below, but it gives me error message "keyError: score_binned"

```
heatmap_data['score_binned'] = heatmap_data['score_binned'].astype(str)
```

Did also try below, which gave me error message "module 'pandas' has no attribute 'astype'", which makes me think that you might not be able to convert data types in pivot tables the same way as a normal dataframe? (Although heatmap_data is classed as a data frame when checking).

```
heatmap_data['amount_binned'] = pd.astype(heatmap_data['amount_binned'])
```

What I want to accomplish is the heatmap below + text on each square that says what the value of avg_converted is.

[image]

Comment: You can try this to change to str, `heatmap_data['score_binned'] = [str(i) for i in heatmap_data['score_binned']`

Comment: Hmm, something is missing in it that you might think I know that I should add? :D I get errorMessage: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: Perhaps because we're referring it back to the same column. Try assign it to a new variable and then assign the new variable to the column

Comment: Sorry, not that good at Python yet. Would you mind writing me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Convert your strings to numeric by removing the '%' and using `pandas.to_numeric`:

```
heatmap_data = (df_grouped_heatmap
                .assign(avg_converted=lambda d: pd.to_numeric(d['avg_converted'].str.strip('%')))
                .pivot(index='score_binned', columns='amount_binned')
                ['avg_converted'].fillna(0)
               )
```

output plot:

[image]

Comment: the bins score_binned and amount_binned in the example table are dtype 'category', the avg_score and avg_converted are floats (no % in real table, that's my bad). But when I turn the table to a pivot table all variables turns to float64. I believe score_binned and amount_binned should be string or category to be able to make a heatmap out of it, but doesn't seem to be able to convert it with a normal astype-function

Comment: Tried print(heatmap_data['score_binned'].to_string()) now, and it says 'keyError: Score_binned' here as well

Comment: Hey again :D Can I do something like this instead but add another column to be converted to string?  heatmap_data1 = (df_grouped_heatmap
                .assign(score_binned=lambda d: pd.to_string(d['score_binned']))
                .pivot(index='score_binned', columns='amount_binned')
                ['avg_converted'].fillna(0)
               )

Comment: I think I don't understand your issue. You need numerical value for the heatmap…

Comment: Hmm, yes I the value avg_converted needs to be numerical, which they are now. It's float64. But answer who helped this person in this thread with same error message as me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58515938/typeerror-object-of-type-interval-is-not-json-serializable-in-plotly-python said the only thing that person needed to do was to convert the categories (in my case floats) to string. When I'm trying to convert score_binned and amount_binned from float to string I get the error messages I've written in my question above :(